# SQL Server 2014 login issue

Tags: sql-server, configuration, logins

I have a login issue here. I created a new user login in SQL Server 2014. I tried to connect to my database using this new login and the below error pops up

> Message
>   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.

I searched for the error and found out that I have to be in mixed authentication mode. I went to properties of the server and changed it to mixed mode from security tab, restarted SQL Server and still the same issue. I tried to investigate more and when I tried the below query

```
SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode]
```

It shows that I'm still in Windows Authentication mode, although the fact is that I changed it to mixed mode.

I am still stuck with this issue and am not able to identify the problem. Can anyone help me out?

I am connecting from SSMS, not code.

Right clicking the server and going to `properties -> security`, shows SQL Server and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always happens because during setup you forgot to adjust your instance to be in both Windows and server authentication. Open SQL Server Management Studio; log in using Windows authentication; right click on your server  then properties, then security tab, and mark on both Windows and server authentication; then click ok.

Close SSMS then here is the trick:

- start SQL Server configuration
- stop all the services
- restart all the services

then you will be able to connect in SQL Server authentication.